# Achieving following effect with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

At the moment this is my transition.

```
$(".element").css("visibility", "visible");
```

element is made hidden in css and than javascript makes it visible

but what I wan't to achieve is sort of microsofty looking effect, basically I want element to slide in from bottom to top (so I assume negative margin at the bottom and than make it positive with javascript) and also while it is sliding in, fade it in from 0 opacity to full opacity, and both effects should have some sort of duration, combined together they should look really good.

Comment: Check out http://api.jquery.com/animate/.

Comment: First , Try that yourself.

Comment: You may also find jQuery's [`show()`](http://api.jquery.com/show/), [`hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/), [`slideUp()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/), and [`slideDown()`](http://api.jquery.com/slideDown/) helpful.

Comment: can you add a link to a _microsofty effect_ for people who are not acquainted with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start with 0 opacity and a small top margin, then animate it in place using `.animate()`. Try something like:

```
$(".element").css({
    opacity: 0,
    visibility: 'visible',
    marginTop: 20
}).animate({
    marginTop: 0,
    opacity: 1
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pc8q6/

Note that you can achieve similar effect using CSS transitions as well, demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Pc8q6/1/ (webkit)

Comment: worked really good! any chance to delay animation just a little bit more? say 500ms?

Comment: @IlyaKnaup I think you can figure that one out: http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

Look at **jQuery**'s `.animate()` : http://api.jquery.com/animate/ ;)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `$(".element").slideToggle('slow')` and `$(".element").show('slow')`

There is not need to use `.animate()` here..

http://api.jquery.com/slideToggle/ - Have a look at the demo!

Answer (score 0):

If you want a solution fully in jQuery, try these two:

[fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/)

[slideUp()](http://api.jquery.com/slideUp/) (or slideToggle() would work as well, depending on how you write your script)